# Permission check in Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, permissions, ionic-framework

My ionic app requires users current location. So the first time the user installs the app normally there is a permission window prompts with some message and Allow/Don't allow options (iOS here). 
Is there a way in Ionic to check if the user actually allowed the app to use his/her location ? In other words the check whether he/she pressed Allow or Don't Allow ?

This is how am I using Cordova Geolocation plugin in my Ionic App to get the users location:

```
.service('LocationService', function($cordovaGeolocation,$q) {
        return {

            getLocation: function(){

                var coordinates = $q.defer();
                $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function (position) {


                        coordinates.resolve({
                            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                            longitude: position.coords.longitude
                        })

                });

                return coordinates;

            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I ended up with checking what value $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition() returns, but that didn't solve my initial problem, therefore I can say that was a workaround...